# Помогите поправить условие в запросе MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

На рисунке изображена диаграмма базы данных, таблица студентов и экзаменов, связь многие ко многим. Дело в том, что мне необходимо получить список студентов, у которых сессия сдана на отлично, но этого не получается сделать, поскольку выводятся и те, у кого например есть 5, но он троечник(т.е. помимо 5 у него есть еще другие оценки и его нельзя отнести к списку отличников). Помогите пожалуйста правильно написать условие (т.е. чтобы у студента все оценки были 5) :(

[image: Диаграмма]

Comment: Первая мысль - пойти от обратного и выбрать все записи "на отлично", а после крепить к ним студентов

Comment: А почему не работает условие WHERE mark > 4?

Comment: А вы специально запрос картинкой приложили, что бы отвечающему пришлось сначала перебивать его с картинки, что бы внести небольшие правки ?  А так то, надо выбросить distinct, сгруппировать по всем полям, которые есть в выборке, и проверить `having min(mark)=5`

Comment: @Stalker потому что если у студента есть и 5 и 3, то он все равно посмотрит, что у него есть 5 и отнесет его к отличникам, а не к троечникам, т.к. оценки по нескольким предметам

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое!!! заработало)

Comment: Это только мне кажется странным, что оценка - mark - находится в таблице Exam, а не в таблице Student_exam?

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант 1:**

```
SELECT X, Y, Z
  FROM ....
 GROUP BY X, Y, Z
HAVING MIN(mark) = 5;
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
SELECT X, Y, Z
  FROM Student T
 WHERE 5 = (
         SELECT MIN(mark)
           FROM student_exam S, exam E
          WHERE E.examId = S.examId AND T.StudentId = S.StudentId
       );
```

Другие варианты на ту же тему, только с подзапросами вида exitst/not exists.

Comment: Mike, мне представляется, что решение нужно дополнить условием, что сданы все экзамены.

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko На текущей схеме это невозможно, потому что нет таблицы, которая бы содержала список возможных экзаменов. ей конечно могла бы быть exam, но тогда в ней не должно было быть оценки. А если даже это она, то по хорошему нужны еще таблицы у какой группы какие должны быть экзамены и т.п.

Comment: Mike, оценка должна быть в таблице Student_exam. По поводу групп понятно.